# Running average but reset when increasing streak stops

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

Original Dataset

```
+---------+--------+------------+
| Product |  Date  | Units Sold |
+---------+--------+------------+
| Prod A  | 1/1/19 |        100 |
| Prod A  | 1/2/19 |        200 |
| Prod A  | 1/3/19 |        300 |
| Prod A  | 1/4/19 |        136 |
| Prod A  | 1/5/19 |        116 |
| Prod A  | 1/6/19 |        120 |
| Prod A  | 1/7/19 |        140 |
| Prod A  | 1/8/19 |        160 |
+---------+--------+------------+
```

Desired Output (Last two columns)

```
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------+------+--------+--------------------+
| Product |  Date  | Units Sold | Previous Units Sold | Diff | Streak | Streak Running Avg |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------+------+--------+--------------------+
| Prod A  | 1/1/19 |        100 |                     |  100 |      1 |                100 |
| Prod A  | 1/2/19 |        200 |                 100 |  100 |      2 |                150 |
| Prod A  | 1/3/19 |        300 |                 200 |  100 |      3 |                200 |
| Prod A  | 1/4/19 |        100 |                 300 | -200 |      0 |                  0 |
| Prod A  | 1/5/19 |        200 |                 100 |  100 |      1 |                200 |
| Prod A  | 1/6/19 |        300 |                 200 |  100 |      2 |                250 |
| Prod A  | 1/7/19 |        200 |                 300 | -100 |      0 |                  0 |
| Prod A  | 1/8/19 |        200 |                 200 |    0 |      0 |                  0 |
+---------+--------+------------+---------------------+------+--------+--------------------+
```

My goal is to calculate running average only when the difference between previous day sale and current day sale is positive (i.e. when the streak >0 calculate calculate the running average.)

For example, Day 1, 2, & 3 have diff positive i.e. 100
therefore the running average for

- Day 1 is 100 (100/1)
- Day 2 is 150 (100+200)/2
- Day 3 is 200 (100+200+300)/3

My Query

```
select *,        
CASE WHEN flag=1 then sum(units) over (partition by item_name order by order_date) else 0 end    as running_avg_sum
from 
(select *,
       lag(units, 1) over (partition by product order by order_date) as previous_day_units
       CASE WHEN units > previous_day_units then 1 else 0 end as flag
from (
         SELECT product,
                order_date,
                SUM(units_sold) units
         FROM product_table
         GROUP BY 1, 2
     ) tbl
     )
```

But above query throws

> Invalid operation: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause;

I'm aware how to resolve the error by adding `rows between unbounded preceding and current row` in the window function but that way it would average all preceding rows. I'm now sure how can I achieve the desired output.

If there's a way to define boundaries, that'd be really helpful

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

---

Insert commands incase you want to replicate

```
CREATE TABLE product_table
(
  product varchar(200),
  order_date timestamp,
  units_sold bigint
)     
 
INSERT INTO product values("Prod A","2019-01-01","100");
INSERT INTO product values("Prod A","2019-01-02","200");
INSERT INTO product values("Prod A","2019-01-03","300");
INSERT INTO product values("Prod A","2019-01-04","136");
INSERT INTO product values("Prod A","2019-01-05","116");
INSERT INTO product values("Prod A","2019-01-06","120");
INSERT INTO product values("Prod A","2019-01-07","140");
INSERT INTO product values("Prod A","2019-01-08","160");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat tricky gaps and islands problem.  Using the difference in row numbers method, we can try:

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, LAG(units_sold, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY order_date) AS prev_units_sold,
              units_sold - LAG(units_sold, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY order_date) diff
    FROM product_table
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY order_date) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product, diff > 0 ORDER BY order_date) rn2
    FROM cte1
)

SELECT product, order_date, units_sold, prev_units_sold, diff,
    CASE WHEN diff > 0
         THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product, rn1 - rn2 ORDER BY order_date)
         ELSE 0 END AS streak,
    CASE WHEN diff > 0
         THEN AVG(units_sold) OVER (PARTITION BY product, rn1 - rn2 ORDER BY order_date)
         ELSE 0 END AS running_avg
FROM cte2
ORDER BY product, order_date;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

The first pass CTE is required to compute the lag number of units sold, per product as ordered by order date.  The second CTE computes two different row number sequences.  The first one is simply ordered by order date.  The second computes two separate sequences for positive diff and negative diff records.  The  difference between the first and second sequence can be used to identify the "islands" over which we want to display the streak and streak average.  For the negative diff records, we just report zero for the streak and streak average.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out Tim. I get two error with this approach - `Invalid operation: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause;` & `Invalid operation: Default parameter not be supported for window function lag;`. I was able to fix lag part by remove `0`.

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer in this case.

Comment: I couldn't solve it completely. Just half of it.